# Starting instrumentation tests from the play icon in Android Studio runs them as JUnit on the JVM

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, android-instrumentation

When I try to run instrumentation tests in Android Studio by clicking the Play icon in the gutter on the left of a file, it creates the wrong run configuration.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1. This seems to only happen if the test is written in Kotlin.